# How to perform aggregation to SQL created columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculation

I have this data in SQL Server

| Name | Nationality | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anonymous | Chinese | M |
| Anonymous | Russian | F |
| Anonymous | German | F |
| Anonymous | Chinese | F |
| Anonymous | American | M |
| Anonymous | German | M |

I can return the count of nationalities separated by distinct values by:

```
SELECT
    Nationality,
    COUNT(*) AS [Nat.Count]  
FROM
    [table1]
GROUP BY
    Nationality
```

| Nationality | Nat.Count |
| --- | --- |
| Chinese | 2 |
| Russian | 1 |
| German | 2 |
| American | 1 |

How can I do it so that I have a "Total" row appended to the bottom (see below)? ...just like AutoSum in Excel?

| Nationality | Nat.Count |
| --- | --- |
| Chinese | 2 |
| Russian | 1 |
| German | 2 |
| American | 1 |
| **Total** | **6** |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to using a `UNION` [you can use `GROUP BY ROLLUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?#group-by-rollup).

The advantage to this approach is that you don't need to repeat your query's body all-over-again.

Because `ROLLUP` uses `NULL` for ignored grouping-keys, you'll need to use either a CTE or inner-query to adapt that to 'Total', and/or sort it so it's the last row, like so:

```sql
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (
    Nationality nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Gender      char(1)       NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tbl ( Nationality, Gender )
VALUES
( N'Chinese' , 'M' ),
( N'Russian' , 'F' ),
( N'German'  , 'F' ),
( N'Chinese' , 'F' ),
( N'American', 'M' ),
( N'German'  , 'M' );

-----

WITH counts AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Nationality ) AS r,
        Nationality,
        COUNT(*) AS "Nat.Count"
    FROM
        @tbl
    GROUP BY ROLLUP
        ( Nationality )
)
SELECT
    ISNULL( Nationality, 'Total' ) AS Nationality,
    "Nat.Count"
FROM
    counts
ORDER BY
    /* This puts the 'Total' row last, but sorts all other rows by `Nationality`: */
    CASE WHEN counts.Nationality IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    counts.r
```

Or, more succintly:

```sql
SELECT
    ISNULL( t.Nationality, 'Total' ) AS Nationality,
    COUNT(*) AS "Nat.Count"
FROM
    @tbl AS t
GROUP BY ROLLUP
    ( t.Nationality )
ORDER BY
    /* This puts the 'Total' row last, but sorts all other rows by `Nationality`: */
    CASE WHEN t.Nationality IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    t.Nationality;
```

- Note that `GROUP BY ROLLUP` *always* requires the `GROUP BY` column list to be delimited with parentheses, even if you only specify a single column name.

  - So this won't work:

    ```sql
    GROUP BY ROLLUP
        t.Nationality
    ```

---

Fun-fact: `GROUP BY ROLLUP` also works with aggregate functions with inner criteria, so it's trivial to modify the query to add a breakdown of genders by country *and* get those numbers in the total:

```sql
SELECT
    ISNULL( t.Nationality, 'Total' ) AS Nationality,
    COUNT(*) AS "COUNT( People )",
    COUNT( CASE Gender WHEN 'F' THEN 1 END ) AS "COUNT( Females )",
    COUNT( CASE Gender WHEN 'M' THEN 1 END ) AS "COUNT( Males )",
    COUNT( CASE WHEN Gender NOT IN ( 'F', 'M' ) THEN 1 END ) AS "COUNT( Other )"
FROM
    @tbl AS t
GROUP BY ROLLUP
    ( t.Nationality )
ORDER BY
    /* This puts the 'Total' row last, but sorts all other rows by `Nationality`: */
    CASE WHEN t.Nationality IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    t.Nationality;
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Comment: Don't we normally qualify column names with `[]` in SQL Server?

Comment: @DaleK Double-quotes are ANSI/ISO SQL-compliant syntax. Considering that SQL Server has had `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` as the default since at least SQL Server 2000 (has it ever been disabled by default?) I think it should be the preferred syntax. I've never, ever, encountered a database in my life that had `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` so yeah. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 2):

Thats normally a front end job... its a bit odd to need to do it as part of your query. But if you have to...

```
SELECT Nationality, COUNT(*) AS [Nat.Count]  
FROM [table1]
GROUP BY Nationality

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total', COUNT(*)
FROM [table1]
```